# How to populate a field of a subdocument which is an array element of another document?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mean-stack, mern

```
let collection = await Collection.findOne({ 'works._id': req.params.id }).populate('works.0.photo');
```

This code will populate the `work` subdoc in index 0, however I want it to populate the index that corresponds to `req.params.id`.

I want something like `.populate('works.i.photo')`, where `i` represents the index of the work which contains an `_id` that matches `req.params.id`.

---

I figured out how to do it, but I'm certain there's a better way.

```
let collection = await Collection.findOne({ 'works._id': req.params.id });
const idx = collection.works.findIndex(work => work._id == req.params.id);
collection = await collection.populate(`works.${idx}.photo`).execPopulate();
```

This doesn't look like the intended way of doing this. Is it possible to do it without iterating to find the index? Preferably with just a single query execution.

Comment: It would be easy if you can provide some sample documents & expected result !!

Comment: @srinivasy I've added some more details, however I'm not sure what you mean however as there is no other information I can provide about my question.

Comment: Do you've to do it using mongoose or is it ok to do it using mongoDB's native feature $lookup (more or less both should work similar) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is something like this :

**someCollection :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dc9c61959f03a3d68cfb8d3"),
    "works" : []
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dc9c72e59f03a3d68cfd009"),
    "works" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 123,
            "photoId" : ObjectId("5dc9c6ae59f03a3d68cfc584")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 456,
            "photoId" : ObjectId("5dc9c6b659f03a3d68cfc636")
        }
    ]
}
```

**photo Collection :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dc9c6ae59f03a3d68cfc584"),
    "photo" : "yes"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dc9c6b659f03a3d68cfc636"),
    "photo" : "no"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dc9c6c259f03a3d68cfc714"),
    "photo" : "yesno"
}
```

**Mongoose Schemas :**

```
const photoSchema = new Schema({
    _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    photo: String,
});

const someColSchema = new Schema({
    _id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId },
    works: [{ _id: { type: Number }, photoId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'photo' } }]
});

const someCol = mongoose.model('someCollection', someColSchema, 'someCollection');
const photoCol = mongoose.model('photo', photoSchema, 'photo');
```

**Code :**

**1) Using Mongoose populate ([Mongoose Populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)) :**

```
let values = someCol.find({"works._id": 123}, {_id: 0, 'works.$': 1}).populate('works.photoId').lean(true).exec();
```

**2) Using mongoDB's native $lookup ([mongoDB $lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html)) :**

```
someCol.aggregate([{ $match: { 'works._id': 123 } }, { $unwind: '$works' }, { $match: { 'works._id': 123 } }, {
    $lookup:
    {
        from: "photo",
        localField: "works.photoId",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "doc"
    }
}, { $project: { _id: 0, doc: { $arrayElemAt: ["$doc", 0] } } }])
```

Both should work similar, in aggregation we're doing `$match` to filter given criteria & `$unwind` to unwrap works array & again doing a filter to only retain values in array that match filter criteria & then doing `$lookup` to fetch respective document from other collection.

Comment: Great answer. That projection syntax `'works.$': 1` was exactly what I was missing. Just to clarify, the `$` sign means the element that matched the query right?

Comment: @AnthonyYershov : Yes it is (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/), but I think it has a down side - only if your array has duplicate values it might return only first found matched value, but in your case it shouldn't be an issue as I expect you won't be having any duplicates in works array !! Anyway just keeping the ref here as it's worth to know about it..